# How to interpret binomial GLM coefficient w/ proportion as outcome

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model

If I am doing a binomial GLM with a proportion as an outcome--how do I interpret the model coefficients? I understand how it is done when the outcome is an event (e.g., 0/1), but it is less clear to me how to interpret it in this case. Is it still the log odds that the outcome (i.e., proportion) is 1?

A silly example below predicting population-level happiness based on number of televisions. My question is: how do I understand/interpret the coefficient for `n_with_tv` (`0.003524932`)?

```
set.seed(1)
mod_df = data.frame(
  island = 1:10,
  pop = sample(1000, 10)
)
mod_df$n_happy = round(mod_df$pop * sample(seq(.2, .8, .01), 10))
mod_df$prop_happy = mod_df$n_happy / mod_df$pop

mod_df$n_with_tv = round(mod_df$pop * (mod_df$prop_happy + rnorm(10, sd = .10)))
mod_df$prop_with_tv = mod_df$n_with_tv / mod_df$pop

mod_df
#>    island pop n_happy prop_happy n_with_tv prop_with_tv
#> 1       1 836     585  0.6997608       518    0.6196172
#> 2       2 679     353  0.5198822       275    0.4050074
#> 3       3 129      52  0.4031008        48    0.3720930
#> 4       4 930     725  0.7795699       697    0.7494624
#> 5       5 509     310  0.6090373       289    0.5677800
#> 6       6 471     344  0.7303609       356    0.7558386
#> 7       7 299     194  0.6488294       167    0.5585284
#> 8       8 270      78  0.2888889        90    0.3333333
#> 9       9 978     254  0.2597137       133    0.1359918
#> 10     10 187      52  0.2780749        48    0.2566845

mod_glm = glm(prop_happy ~ n_with_tv,
              weights = pop,
              family = "binomial",
              data = mod_df)

summary(mod_glm)$coef
#>                 Estimate   Std. Error   z value      Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept) -0.924823050 0.0551110306 -16.78109  3.356306e-63
#> n_with_tv    0.003524932 0.0001494939  23.57910 6.315129e-123
```

Possibly related:

- [How to interpret GLM coefficient (binomial, continue value)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388929/how-to-interpret-glm-coefficient-binomial-continue-value)
- [Reference to support using binomial GLM for proportion response](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263902/reference-to-support-using-binomial-glm-for-proportion-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This model is called the "fractional logit". You actually should be using a robust standard error and the quasibinomal family for this kind of analysis since the outcome does not have a binomial distribution.

The coefficient does not have a useful interpretation; it is essentially the same as with logistic regression on a binary event: a coefficient of $b$ means that a 1-unit change in $x$ is associated with a $b$-unit change in the logit of the outcome, where $\text{logit}(y) = \log\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)$. We can't speak about probabilities or odds and instead can only interpret the logit as a complicated nonlinear function of the outcome.

For this reason, fractional logit models are often interpreted using marginal effects. The Stata [documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rfracreg.pdf) of `fracreg` explains these models and describes how one would use the `margins` command after fitting the model to appropriately interpret the model results. When the outcome is a probability, it might be possible to use a log-odds interpretation. In your case, you might be able to interpret the coefficient as the change in the log odds of an individual on an island being happy given a change in the number of TVs on that island. But this interpretation extrapolates a bit from what the model allows, and the marginal effects approach would be preferred.

In R, you can use `marginaleffects::avg_slopes()` to compute the average marginal effect of the predictor, which can be interpreted as the average rate of change in the outcome corresponding to a change in the predictor (or the average of pointwise derivatives of the average dose-response function across the sample). Se my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/500849/116195) for more intuition on interpreting these quantities.

Comment: Very helpful--thank you, Noah!